# How to get desired number of rows for each group / category in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, rows, row-number

I have this query for retrieving rows from a SQL Server table:

```
SELECT
    aid, 
    research_area_category_id, 
    CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100)) [research_area], 
    COUNT(*) [Paper_Count]
FROM
    sub_aminer_paper 
GROUP BY
    aid, 
    research_area_category_id,
    CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100))
HAVING 
    aid IN (SELECT
                aid
            FROM 
                sub_aminer_paper
            GROUP BY 
                aid
            HAVING 
                MIN(p_year) = 1990 AND MAX(p_year) = 2014 AND COUNT(pid) BETWEEN 10 AND 40
            )
ORDER BY aid ASC, Paper_Count DESC
```

which returns this output:

```
aid     research_area_category_id   research_area                Paper_Count  
2937    33                          markov chain                 3  
2937    33                          markov decision process      1  
2937    1                           optimization problem         1  
2937    27                          real time application        1  
2937    32                          software product lines       1  
11120   29                          aspect oriented programming  4  
11120   1                           graph cut                    2  
11120   1                           optimization problem         2  
11120   32                          uml class diagrams           1  
11120   25                          chinese word segmentation    1   
11120   29                          dynamic programming          1  
11120   19                          face recognition             1  
11120   1                           approximation algorithm      1  
12403   2                           differential equation        7  
12403   1                           data structure               2  
12403   34                          design analysis              1  
12403   9                           object detection             1  
12403   27                          operating system             1  
12403   1                           problem solving              1  
12403   21                          archiving system             1  
12403   2                           calculus                     1
```

Now this is returning the output including all of rows concerned with respective `aid`'s whereas I need only first 3 rows for each `aid` ORDER BY `Paper_Count` DESC i.e. rows containing value of `Paper_Count` `3, 1, 1` for `aid` `2937`, `4,2,2` for `11120` and `7,2,2` for `12403`.

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Use a CTE with DENSE_RANK OVER..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to apply `row_number() over(partition by aid order by Paper_Count desc) as rn` on your resultset and then select all records with `rn<=3`

```
with cte
as
(
SELECT
    aid, 
    research_area_category_id, 
    CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100)) [research_area], 
    COUNT(*) [Paper_Count]
FROM
    sub_aminer_paper 
GROUP BY
    aid, 
    research_area_category_id,
    CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100))
HAVING 
    aid IN (SELECT
                aid
            FROM 
                sub_aminer_paper
            GROUP BY 
                aid
            HAVING 
                MIN(p_year) = 1990 AND MAX(p_year) = 2014 AND COUNT(pid) BETWEEN 10 AND 40
            )
ORDER BY aid ASC, Paper_Count DESC
)
,
cte1
AS
( 
   SELECT * ,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aid ORDER BY Paper_Count DESC) AS rn 
   FROM cte 
)

SELECT * FROM cte1 WHERE rn<=3
```

Comment: Row_number will return duplicates if paper_count is the same

Comment: @Mihai No it is not returning the duplicates even for same Paper_Count as for the very first `aid` i.e. `2937`, `Paper_Count` is same

Comment: @Taufel You`re right I dont know why I was confusing it with RANK()

Comment: @Mihai : It doesn't return duplicates. It is just like ORDER BY on table column,